# Setting up SSH for WSL using Ubuntu, but can't edit ssd_config file with VSCode WSL2 window. It won't save - "operation not permitted"?

Tags: ssh, lamp, wsl-2, sshd

I'm following [these instructions](https://www.shayanderson.com/microsoft-windows/install-lamp-on-windows-10-with-wsl.htm) to set up LAMP on WSL. I got to step 3, and made the edits it instructed after "Make these edits:". However, after editing sshd_config **using VSCode (in a WSL-2 window**, which I figured might matter), I'm unable to save it and continue with the instructions.

VSCode first gives me this error popup when I try to save:
`Failed to save 'sshd_config': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator.`

And when I select "Retry as Admin", it gives another:
`Failed to save 'sshd_config': Command failed: "C:\Users\smith\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd" --file-write "c:\Users\smith\AppData\Roaming\Code\code-elevated-BmAuYzjZ" "\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\etc\ssh\sshd_config" Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\etc\ssh\sshd_config'`

What do I need to do to be able to use VSCode to make the edits to this file? I don't want to be locked into only being able to use Nano for this or any project, so I'd be very thankful for some guidance.

---

UPDATE: I think I've made a little headway! I tried following this similar tutorial, but on this step, trying to add this file, I get an error. I think I'm lacking some kind of permission to change WSL files in Explorer at all.
[image: Popup that says "You need permission to perform this action]
I'll try to figure out how to do this before going further, and I'll report back if I'm successful.